# Custom fields with Membership provider

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am trying to use the custom membership provider with my custom user class from my dbcontext but I am experiencing problems when trying to create a new user using the "Register" form. I have fields such as **Points** etc in my user class that need to be initialised upon creation of the user.

When I call:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

There is no way for me to add these details in. How can I use this so that I can autopopulate these values with zero for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out this overload which allows you to specify custom properties:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(
    userName: model.UserName, 
    password: model.Password,
    propertyValues: new
    {
        foo = "bar",
        baz = "bazinga",
    }
)
```